# Derivatives of measures of bounded variation on intervals

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability

Investigating an abstract Cauchy problem on the space of measures with bounded variation I came up with the following space:

Let $\operatorname{BV}[a,b]$ the space of all functions $f:[0, 1] \to \mathbb C$ with bounded variation, i.e., the supremum of $\sum_{i = 1}^n \lvert f(x_i) - f(x_{i - 1}) \rvert$ over all finite partitions $\lbrace x_0, \dots, x_n\rbrace$, $n \in \mathbb N$, is finite. Now consider the "Sobolev measure space"
$$\mathrm{M}^1[a,b] := \lbrace \mu \in \mathrm{M}[a,b] : \exists \, f \in \operatorname{BV}[a,b] : \mu = f \, \mathrm d x\rbrace. $$
Since each function of bounded variation is differentiable almost everywhere, it is possible, to define the operator
$$A := \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}, \quad A\mu := f', \quad D(A) := \mathrm{M}^1[a,b]. $$
I would like to know if operators in spirit of $A$ and spaces in spirit of $\mathrm{M}^1[a,b]$ are already covered in the existing literature.

**Remark:** A concept closely related to my questing is the so called *Skohorod differentiability* that can be found for instance in *Bogachev, Vladimir I.*, Differentiable measures and the Malliavin calculus, [ZBL1247.28001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1247.28001). However, the definition of this kind of differentiability is then defined only for measures on $\mathbb R$ via the duality to $C_b(\mathbb R)$. It is then proven that a measure on $\mathbb R$ is Skohorod differentiable if and only if it has a density of bounded variation, which was my main motiviation to define the space above. But I cannot believe that I am the first to come up with the pretty simple idea to consider this space.

Comment: if $f$ is just of bounded variation, then $f'$ is a measure and hence, its not clear to me how to multiply $f'$ with the Lebesgue measure. Put differently: What do you hope to get for $A\mu$ when $f$ is the Heaviside function?

Comment: You are right! I edited my question, accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps reading [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3257743/existence-of-int-abf-dg-when-f-g-not-in-bva-b/3279128#3279128) would be somewhat useful: it describes an old result of of Ivan Petrovskii and Renato Caccioppoli identifying conditions for which $$h(x)=\int\limits_a^x f(t)\mathrm{d}g(t) \quad f,g\in C^0$$ exists, without necessarily requiring $f\in BV$ or $g\in BV$.

Comment: If I see correctly, your $M^1[a,b]$ is exactly $BV[a,b]$ where you interpret the functions in $BV$ as measures by multiplying them with the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Dirk Yes, exactly. But I am mainly interested in references about operators from type $A$ (closedness, weak*-closedness, etc.) and maybe about results like weak*-density for its domain.